AKS SecretProviderClass get and mount openssl generated pfx cert with private key - Secrets Store CSI Driver
I am creating the my-cert-name cert:
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out key.pem -traditional 2048
openssl req -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -config openssl.cnf
openssl pkcs12 -export -out my-cert-name.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem

Then cert is imported to KeyVault.
How to get cert pfx from KeyVault with SecretProviderClass on AKS?
Using objectType: cert create secret without private key inside, only certificate.
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: {{ .Values.managedIdentityClientId }}
    keyvaultName: {{ .Values.keyVaultName }}
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: my-cert-name
          objectType: cert
    tenantId: {{ .Values.tenantId }}
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: {{ template "api.fullname" . }}-certs
    data:
    - key: my-cert-name.pfx
      objectName: my-cert-name
    type: Opaque

Certificate works fine when is directly attached and deployed within application, but we want to get rid of certs from repo.

In order to retrieve only the certificate (without the private key) from your Key Vault using Secrets Store CSI Driver. When using the objectType: cert in the SecretProviderClass, it should be used to fetch just the public certificate from the Key Vault, and not the private key i.e. instead of retrieving a PFX file (which contains both the certificate and private key), you can retrieve the public certificate only by using objectType: cert in the SecretProviderClass.
example-
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: my-cert-secretprovider
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    keyvaultName: myKeyVault201
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: my-cert-name
          objectType: cert
    tenantId: "abcd-efgh-ijk-lmnop-qrst"
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: my-cert-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: my-cert-name.crt      
      objectName: my-cert-name




Verify the Mounted Certificate
kubectl exec -it my-app-pod -- ls /mnt/secrets


updated SecretProviderClass for PFX file
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: my-cert-secretprovider
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: {{ .Values.managedIdentityClientId }}  
    keyvaultName: {{ .Values.keyVaultName }}  
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: my-cert-name
          objectType: secret  
          objectVersion: ""   
    tenantId: {{ .Values.tenantId }}
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: {{ template "api.fullname" . }}-certs
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: my-cert-name.pfx   
      objectName: my-cert-name

Found few MS Docs-

Set up Secrets Store CSI Driver to enable NGINX Ingress Controller with TLS
Connect your Azure identity provider to the Azure Key Vault Secrets Store CSI Driver in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) (access-with-a-user-assigned-managed-identity)


I need both public & private part of cert. Therefore I need the pfx file.

In that case I have updated the SecretProviderClass which should includes both the public and private parts of the certificate.

Create a PEM file with both private and public keys. Import it to Azure KeyVault/Certificate.
secretProviderClass.yml should look like
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: spc-tls
  namespace: your-namespace
spec:
  parameters:
    keyvaultName: kv-name
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: certificate-name-as-in-azure
          objectType: secret
          
    tenantId: .....
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"                        
    userAssignedIdentityID: ......
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: tls-crt
      type: kubernetes.io/tls
      data:
        - key: tls.key
          objectName: certificate-name-as-in-azure
        - key: tls.crt
          objectName: certificate-name-as-in-azure

